# Defer val definition in Scala

Tags: scala

Have the following:

```
    var jdt : JDateTime = null

    try {
        jdt = new JDateTime(timeString, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,mss")
    } catch {
        case e : Exception => return Option.empty
    }
```

I would like `jdt` to be `val`, as it is a constant value. Is there any scala syntax trick that can work here? Like, in case of exception, set `null` etc.

Comment: By the way, everything is an expression in Scala, so you could have also just done `val jdt = try {` ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a syntax trick, just library usage:

```
import scala.util.Try

val jdt = Try(new JDateTime(timeString, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,mss")).toOption.orNull
```

Alhough, I would suggest leaving it at `Option` instead of using `null`.

Comment: I would argue against using orNull - a better solution would be to keep your JDateTime wrapped in a Try or some other datatype that meets your needs such as Option or \/

Comment: @melps I agree and suggested it as well. I only included it since OP asked specifically about null.

Answer (score 2):

This is also allowed since try produces a result:

```
val jdt = 
    try {
        new JDateTime(timeString, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,mss")
    } catch {
        case e : Exception => return Option.empty
    }
```

Even in java I can do this with final since I defer setting the variable until I have to:

```
final Date date;
try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat().parse("");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    return null;
}
```